# How come @override works in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading, overriding

I need somebody who take a look at what I think about these lines of code.

```
class AAA
{ 
public void rideMethod(){System.out.println("AAA's Method");
public void loadMethod(){"void Method"};
}
class BBB extends AAA
{ 
public void rideMethod(){System.out.println("BBB's Method");
public void loadMethod(int num){"int Method"};
}
class CCC extends BBB
{ 
public void rideMethod(){System.out.println("CCC's Method");
public void loadMethod(double num){"double Method"};
}

class Ride
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  AAA ref1 = new CCC();   
  BBB ref2 = new CCC();   
  CCC ref3 = new CCC();

  ref1.rideMethod();
  ref2.rideMethod();
  ref3.rideMethod();


  ref3.loadMethod(); 
  ref3.loadMethod(1);
  ref3.loadMethod(1.2);
 }
}
//These are results. 
CCC's Method 
CCC's Method 
CCC's Method 
void Method
int Method
double Method
```

Here is what I take.

The CCC() for ref# in the main scope which inherits AAA() and BBB()is the thing we can refer to the box containing every aspect of classes here. and AAA,BBB and CCC (as a class type) for ref# is like a boundary we can access to. Since ref# has been initialised using CCC() and the concept of @override is adapted, Syso("CCC's Method") must occurs as a result. 
Each loadMethod will split out "void int and double Method" because the classes they initially used are AAA and BBB.
thanks for reading!

Comment: What's your question exactly? Also, you mention `@override`, but there's no `@override` in your code...

Comment: is this a question? I can't understand where is the problem

Comment: [Overriding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) != [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Comment: No way the last three result lines came from the provided code: they should all say "void Method"

Comment: sorry guys, I made a mistake and modified codes.

Comment: I want to discuss about what I thought is right or not.  Whether I take AAA and BBB, CCC class type for ref# is fine to think as if ACCESS METHOD in terms of overloading .

Comment: AAA ref1 = new CCC();   
       BBB ref2 = new CCC();   
       CCC ref3 = new CCC();

Comment: Is there anyone who can explain how it works inside the complier? ..

Comment: @jay Now that is a question, and I have added to my answer. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 AAA ref1 = new CCC(); 
 BBB ref2 = new CCC(); 
 CCC ref3 = new CCC();
```

> Is there anyone who can explain how it works inside the complier?

In this case `ref1` is a reference to a `AAA` object and since `CCC` inherits from `AAA` it is also an `AAA` so this assignment is allowed by the compiler and by the JVM.  `ref2` is a reference to a `BBB` and since `new CCC()` is also a `BBB` by inheritance this assignment is allowed.

---

EDIT: With your modified code, it prints as you expect as you are calling `loadMethod(int)` and `loadMethod(double)`

In the first three calls you are using an overridden method, in the second three calls you are using an overloaded method.

---

Before your edit....

If you correct the code so it compiles you get

```
CCC's Method
CCC's Method
CCC's Method
void Method
void Method
void Method
```

run here http://ideone.com/r7K2wI

I sort of get what you are trying to say up to "Syso("CCC's Method") must occurs as a result." but

> Each loadMethod will split out "void int and double Method" because the classes they initially used are AAA and BBB.
>   thanks for reading!

No, there is no way a call `loadMethod()` will call `loadmethod(double)` as it can't and doesn't know which `double` you would have passed to it.

Comment: I am pretty upset with the thing people just see and give me a minus on my question board, even though I understand why.

Comment: BTW Thanks for the link.

Comment: @jay it was very hard for me to understand what you were trying to say and I still couldn't say I understand what your question was.

Comment: ref3.loadMethod(); 
  ref3.loadMethod(1);
  ref3.loadMethod(1.2);

Comment: @jay so can you rephrase what your question is?

Comment: In short, can you explain this? AAA ref1 = new CCC();

Comment: @jay I added it to the start of my answer. Do you have a question based on my updated answer?

Comment: nope. I will take it just simply.  I would just consider the use of CCC() in my code to override a specific function.  thanks for your kindness. Peter.

Comment: @jay The key thing to remember that Java only has primitives and reference for variables, Java is always pass by value and references are passed by value. When you call `new CCC()` you are dynamically creating a reference to an object on the heap.